# How to reset vue modal component working with vue-show to use autofocus

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I made modal component using `v-show` options live below.

```
<registerModal v-show="register.etcCompanyVisible" />
```

Thus, when `register.etcCompanyVisible` is `true`, this modal appears. 
And this modal has some input like this.

```
<input type="text" v-model="etcCompanyName" placeholder="name" autofocus />
```

When this modal is opened at first time, the autofocus works well. 
And then, this modal can be closed with cancel button by changing `register.etcComapnyVisible` to `false`.

```
 <button class="btn secondary" v-on:click="etcCompanyVisibleClosed()">Cancel</button>
```

When I open modal again, the autofocus doesn't work. I think it needs some reset option for this modal, but I don't know how it can be done.
Could you give me some recommendation? Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the `autofocus` attribute is only reliable on page load, so you need to handle the focus event yourself.

The easiest way to do this is to put a ref on your input.

```
<input ref="companyName" type="text" v-model="etcCompanyName" placeholder="name"/>
```

Then when you launch your modal, maybe you are using a button, call the focus on that `$ref`.

```
<template>
  ...
  <button @click="focusInput">launch modal</button>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  ...
  methods:{
     foucusInput() {
        this.$refs.companyName.focus();
     }
  }
```

Note that you could use the same method to dynamically focus inputs in a certain order.  Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfvau54p) demonstrating that using button clicks but you could easily use this to move from one input to the next automatically after a certain condition is met.